# For loop each visible row and set value at another column

Tags: excel, vba

My code below has two parts. The first part basically sets a cell as a date that is 6 months from now. This part works but I'm having trouble with the second part.

The second part is after filtering a table, I want to compare each cell in column H (which is a date value) with that future date in the first part. If the date in column H is **after** the future date, cell AI of that row will be set as "Yes"

```
Set Database = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
LastRow = Database.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With Database.Range("AI1")

    'Adds 6 months to today's date in cell AI1 in sheet
    .Formula = "=EDATE(Today(),6)"
    
    'Converts that date to 1st day of the month (e.g. 17/01/2020 is converted to 01/01/2020
    .Value = DateSerial(Year(Range("AI1")), Month(Range("AI1")), 1)

End With

For i = 2 To LastRow

    'This line throws a run-time error 13: type mismatch
    If Cells(i, "H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) > Database.Range("AI1") Then
       
       Cells(i, "AI").Value = "Yes"
       
    End If
 
Next i
```

Comment: What you need is to loop over the visible cells, not to loop `For i = 1 to LastRow`.

Comment: Should probably be something like `.Value = DateSerial(Year(.Value), Month(.Value), 1)`... right now `Range("AI1")` is implicitly referring to the `ActiveSheet`, not `Database`.

Comment: What sheet is the second part operating on?

Comment: @TimWilliams the same `Database` sheet

Comment: Then might the first loop iteration replace the value in AI1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work, with the note that it could replace the value in AI1 on the first loop iteration.  Not sure you really want that?

```vba
    Dim c As Range, vis As Range, dt as Date
    
    'calculate cutoff date
    dt = Application.EDate(Date, 6)
    dt = DateSerial(Year(dt), Month(dt), 1)
    
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no visible cells
    Set vis = database.Range("H1:H" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors
    
    If Not vis Is Nothing Then  'any visible cells ?
        For Each c In vis.Cells
            If c.Value > dt Then c.EntireRow.Range("AI1").Value = "Yes"
        Next c
    End If
```

Comment: I can just move that value elsewhere if needed

Comment: Updated to calculate the date in the VBA instead of in a cell on the sheet....

Comment: thanks a lot, I was stuck at this for ages